# JQuery invoke click based on CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable"><tr>
  <td class="col" style="background-color:red" onclick="funct1()"></td>
  <td class="col" style="background-color:blue" onclick="funct2()"><td>
</tr></table>
```

How can I invoke click function if I know only css background-color properties?

I would need a JQuery function like this (pseudo-code):

```
if ('$(#myTable > col ) have background-color = "blue" '){
  $(col with background-color blue).click();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('myTabel > .col').filter(function(){
      return $(this).css('background-color') == 'blue'
 }).click();
```

Or if it's inline style:

```
 $('myTabel > .col[style="background-color:blue"]').click();
```

But you really should give those elements a css class which effect their color:

```
<table id="myTable"><tr>
  <td class="col red"  onclick="funct1()"></td>
  <td class="col blue" onclick="funct2()"><td>
</tr></table>
```

Then select it like that:

```
$('#myTable >.col.blue').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them another class like `bg-red`, `bg-blue` then you could use `$('.col').hasClass('bg-red')`

Comment: You do it even simpler: `$(.col.bg-red)` **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective way to do it but you could select everything and reduce the set manually like this:

```
$( '*' ).filter( function( index ) {
    return $( this ).css( 'background-color' ) == '#0000ff';
} ).click();
```